# A question about Stieltjes integral

Tags: real-analysis

While studying the Riemann - Stieltjes integral, I read this exercise in my book:

"Let $f:[a, b]\to \mathbb{R}$ be a bounded function. Denoted $L(P, f)$ the lower Darboux sum and $|P|$ the mesh of the partition $P$. Prove that for every $\epsilon>0$, there exists $\delta>0$ such that for every partition $P$ with $|P|<\delta$, we have: $\underline{\int_{a}^{b}}f(x)dx-L(P, f)<\epsilon$."

I have a solution for this exercise, but my question is: Can we generalize this problem for Stieltjes integral, with $\underline{\int_{a}^{b}}f(x)d\alpha$ instead of $\underline{\int_{a}^{b}}f(x)dx$?

Particularly, can we have this theorem?

Let $f:[a, b]\to \mathbb{R}$ be a bounded function and $\alpha$ is a monotonic function on $[a, b]$ . Denoted $L(P, f, \alpha)$ the lower Darboux sum and $|P|$ the mesh of the partition $P$. Prove that for every $\epsilon>0$, there exists $\delta>0$ such that $\underline{\int_{a}^{b}}f(x)d\alpha-L(P, f, \alpha)<\epsilon$ for every partition $P$ with $|P|<\delta$?

Comment: The proof is there in Rudin's *Principles of Mathematical Analysis*

Comment: I've read Rudin's book, but I can't find the proof for Stieltjes integral. Can you tell me which chapter?

Comment: In the sixth chapter. In the chapter all properties of integral are for steiltjes integral

Comment: I've read the sixth chapter, but the book doesn't even mention that theorem. Can you give me a hint?

Comment: In my question, $\alpha$ is just a monotonic function, and I don't know how the mesh of the partition relate to the function $\alpha$.

Comment: look at theorem 6.4, or 6.6. The theorem name is not explicitly mentioned. However, I think the theorem is proved

Comment: I don't think so. What I need is the inequality is true for every partition $P$ with $|P|<\delta$

Comment: Rudin says, "For every $\epsilon>0$, there exists a partition $P$", which can be modified to mean the same thing, isnt it?